# Java - How to create a substring until a non-numerical character is reached?

Tags: java, regex, string, variables, numeric

The title speaks for itself. I'm trying to create a calculator that integrates polynomial functions using basic coding, not just whipping out a math operator to do it for me :). I haven't had to go far until I hit a wall, as I'm unable to find a way to: create a substring of the numbers in the original string until a non-numerical character is reached. i.e. if the string is 123x, I want to create a substring of 123, without the 'x'. Here is what I've got so far:

```
public static void indefinite()
{
    int x = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter your function to integrate:\n F ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String function = input.nextLine();
    String s1 = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < function.length(); i++)
    {
        s1 = s1 + function.substring(x, i+1);
        x = i+1;
    }
}
```

It all looks a bit nonsensical, but basically, if the string 'function' is 32x^4, I want the substring to be 32. I'll figure out the rest myself, but this part I cant seem to do.

p.s. i know the for loop's repetition variable is wrong, it shouldn't repeat until the end of the string if I'm looking at functions with more than just 2x^3. I haven't gotten around trying to figure that out yet, so I just made sure it does it for 1 part.

Answer (score 4):

You could split your string at the letter-digit marks, like so:

```
str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
```

For instance, "123x54y7z" will return `[123, x, 54, y, 7, z]`

Answer (score 3):

Use `replaceAll()` to "extract" it:

```
String number = str.replaceAll("\\D.*", "");
```

This replaces the first non digit and everything after it with nothing (effectively deleting it), leaving you with just the number.

You can also go directly to a numeric primitive, without having to use a `String` variable if you prefer (like me) to have less code:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("\\D.*", ""));
```